# Does GORM have a Decimal datatype?

Tags: go, go-gorm

Does [GORM](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm) have a decimal datatype to store money values (-> `Decimal(8,2)`)?

I could not find it on https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm#define-models-structs

Comment: try with a `*math/big.Rat` and if that doesn't work use an `int64` as amount of cents.

Comment: I don't think measure currency with `float32` seems to be a recommended approach. `big.float64`
or
`decimal` github.com/shopspring/decimal
is a better idea indeed.

Comment: Why do you think float64 is significantly better than float32 for currencies? Please note I never suggested to use floats for currencies at all.

Answer (score 23):

Michael's answer works. But If you want to use decimal type with golang, you can use [shopspring/decimal](https://github.com/shopspring/decimal) like this:

```
type TableName struct {
  Amount    decimal.Decimal `json:"amount" sql:"type:decimal(20,8);"`
}
```

Answer (score 12):

This one works for me:

```golang
type Product struct {
      decimal.Decimal `gorm:"type:decimal(7,6);"`
}
```

I was also trying the suggested `sql:` but columns end up as `text` fields in sqlite3 when using gorm's `AutoMigrate()`.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using [AutoMigrate](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm#migration), you can give [GORM SQL instructions (in your struct model)](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm#define-models-structs) on how to build the table. Try something like the following:

```
type Product struct {
Id           int
ProductName  string    `sql:"type:varchar(250);"`
Amount       float32   `sql:"type:decimal(10,2);"` 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a little old but I had this issue and it's very hard to find the answer. if you're using Gorm with liquibase use BigDecimal for any floating point numbers.